# Unable to download zip files in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have the following link on my webpage:

```
 <a href="SaveAll/000023_DocumentsZipped.zip">Download Zipped Folder</a>
```

When I load the page in IE and click the link, I get a message saying

> What do you want to do with 000023_DocumentsZipped_zip? Open/Save/Save As

None of the options works - a message appears saying

> 000023_DocumentsZipped_zip couldn't be downloaded.

In Chrome the download works fine.

Why did IE change the extension to _zip instead of .zip?

When I hover my mouse over the link, the status bar shows the file path with .zip extension.

Comment: Can you post the response headers?

Comment: Did you see [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/couldnt-be-downloaded-appears-at-bottom-of-screen/ad51df58-bd7c-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5)?

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen that, I added this `httpResponse.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/force-download");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                               "attachment;filename="
                               + "SaveAll/000023_DocumentsZipped.zip");`